# why is Time complexity of a Priority Queue enqueue is O(log n)?

Tags: javascript, queue, time-complexity, big-o, priority-queue

when getting time complexity we go by worse case scenario, right?
so each time let's say we are putting an item where we have to loop all the way to the end to find the insertion place then isn't it O(n)?

```
pq = [1,2,3,4]
pq.enqueue(5);
pq.enqueue(6);
```

Isn't in this case enqueue/insert time complexity is O(n)?

Comment: FYI: I mainly use javascript.

Comment: `Isn't in this case enqueue/insert time complexity is O(n)?` For linear search, yes. Nobody does it this way however.

Comment: @tkausl how do they do it?

Comment: priority queues are often [heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure))

Answer (score 1):

PriorityQueue are implemented on Heap (Min Heap by default). And Heaps are basically Tree type Data Structure, where elements are arranged in a specific "priority" basis in left sub-tree or right sub-tree. So while insertion or deletion, in worst case, you need to traverse up and down the **height of the tree**. And the height of the tree is in the order of log n.

I strongly recommend going through the articles.
[Priority Queue on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue)